# resetting joomla state variables

Tags: variables, search, view, joomla, state

I have a page of item list and a filtering area which works for searching. And to pass and retrieve the variables from filter form I use getUserStateFromRequest then I list the items according to these. but when I move between lines or other views then I return back I want to variables are reset to see whole list but it doesn't. I think I should reset them when the view is changed. How to control this or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't want to use *getUserStateFromRequest* at all.
The getUserStateFromRequest will store request variables to the user session.
If you want the state the reset when you leave the page, you could choose not to save the variables in the user session.

Within your model populateState, something like:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$search_term = $app->input->get('search_term', null, 'CMD');
$this->setState('filter.search_term', $search_term);
```

Then to retrive the state (still within your model):

```
$search_term = $this->getState('filter.search_term');
if($search_term != null)
    $query->where('my_field = ' . $db->quote($search_term));
```

Note that the code is not tested.

Comment: I couldnt get it. I  want to do search and select an item to see its details in single item tmp file with same view model and controler of list tmp after seeing the item details if user come back the lsit shoudl be still filtered.

And what is the difference of setState and getStates than getUserState form request. And I couldnt find the input function in docs of joomla in JAPplication calss

Comment: What Joomla version are you using? The "input" in JApplication exists since 2.5 I think. See http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput. Difference between getState and getUserState is that the  getUserState is saved with the user session, meaning that the state consists when the user navigates from page to page. While getState will only be saved on the current user request.

Comment: I am little confused about the mean of request if I click a link the query in the link is sent as request variabile if I am not wrong. Than in my mine a question arises I can retrive a variable with JRequest(); so what is the difference of This and getState. When a request starts and when it ends. Thank you for patient and help Fnatte.

Comment: JRequest is deprecated, and its functionality has been replaced by $app->input. They work pretty much the same. So JRequest::getString('my_var', 'default_value') is the same as $app->input->get('my_var', 'default_value', 'STRING'). In my example in the first answer I use $app->input to get the user request variable sent by the link. Then I push that value into the model state (using $this->setState). Later in that model I can retrieve that value using $this->getState. I'm not the best at explaining, keep on trying:)

Comment: Thanks for your comments again. So I think I it is better to change all JRequest to JInput in all my component :D. But I still dont understand the request mean when it starts and ends. The thing I understood that when a user opens or visits a site his session starts and when he leaves or close the browser or tab or whatever it  is the session ends. What about request ?

Comment: And I dont use populate state I am using by own functions like protected function _buildQueryWhere(){} to get variables and set where statment of database. I tested it. it does filtering but dont store variable if I retrn previous page and click second pagination button the filtering is reset. :S

Comment: If you only want your state to be kept between the pagination, then try to add that variables to the pagination links. That's how com_content works I think. If you send the filter variables by GET-method and not by POST, JPagination should include those variables in the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the active filters like this and then add resetuserstate=1 to the query:

---

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {

    ... ... ...

    parent::populateState('a.title', 'asc');

    $activefilters=$this->getActiveFilters();
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $resetUserState=(bool) $jinput->get("resetuserstate",0, 'INT');        

    if ($resetUserState) {
        foreach ($activefilters as $activefilter => $filterstate) {
            // clearing filters
            $app->setUserState($this->contect . 'filter.'. $activefilter, '');
            $this->setState('filter.'.$activefilter,'');

        }
    } 
}
```

---

NOTE:
Freaky things happen when you muddle up the user state by setting filters incorrectly, logging in and out also clears the user state and helps sometimes.

Answer (score -4):

I still coulnt solve my problem :S. Get is useless. And what is the difference of these codes

```
            $mainframe  =& JFactory::getApplication();

    $filter_carryingW   = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_carryingW', '', 'int' );
    $filter_carryingF   = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_carryingF', '', 'int' );
    $filter_services    = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_services', '', 'int' );
    $filter_country     = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_country', '', 'word' );
    $filter_city        = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_city', '', 'int' );
    $filter_town        = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_town', '', 'int' );

    $this->setState('com_dratransport.members.filter_carryingW' , $filter_carryingW);
    $this->setState('com_dratransport.members.filter_carryingF' , $filter_carryingF);
    $this->setState('com_dratransport.members.filter_services'  , $filter_services);
    $this->setState('com_dratransport.members.filter_country'       , $filter_country);
    $this->setState('com_dratransport.members.filter_city'      , $filter_city);
    $this->setState('com_dratransport.members.filter_town'      , $filter_town);

    $f['filter_carryingW']  = $this->getState('com_dratransport.members.filter_carryingW');
    $f['filter_carryingF']  = $this->getState('com_dratransport.members.filter_carryingF');
    $f['filter_services']   = $this->getState('com_dratransport.members.filter_services');
    $f['filter_country']    = $this->getState('com_dratransport.members.filter_country');
    $f['filter_city']       = $this->getState('com_dratransport.members.filter_city');
    $f['filter_town']       = $this->getState('com_dratransport.members.filter_town');
```

and

```
            $f['filter_carryingW']  = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_carryingW', '', 'int' );
    $f['filter_carryingF']  = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_carryingF', '', 'int' );
    $f['filter_services']   = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_services', '', 'int' );
    $f['filter_country']    = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_country', '', 'word' );
    $f['filter_city']       = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_city', '', 'int' );
    $f['filter_town']       = $mainframe->input->get( 'filter_town', '', 'int' );
```

Comment: is there anybody know this issiue